# Handling hundreds of actions in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2, struts, action

I've inherited a struts 1 web application where, in order to reduce the number of Action classes (I guess this is the reason), lots of actions are mapped inside a single Action class, like:

```
public XXXAction() throws Exception{
     actions = new Hashtable();
     actions.put("/XXX/main/load", new Integer(0));
     actions.put("/XXX/main/save", new Integer(1));
            ......
}

public ActionForward executeAction(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
throws IOException, ServletException
{
try
    {
        switch (((Integer) actions.get(action)).intValue())
        {
         case 0:
          loadXXXMain();
          break;
            case 1:
        .......
```

and so on (in some Action classes I have almost one hundred of these small actions).

Now I'm looking at migrate to struts2 and I would like to have a cleaner and better solution to handle this, maybe without having a single Action class for each of these small classes. What do you suggest? I don't like this solution, but I don't like having hundreds of Action classes....

Thanks!
Roberto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map a single Action class into several urls each one handled by a different method of the class. Check out the Struts2 documentation [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/action-configuration.html). I'm generally used to map a single url to a single Action class, but I think you can also group some urls together if they are related to the same domain concept (like CRUD, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've got a significant refactoring on your hands.  I agree that hundreds of fine-grained Actions doesn't sound like a good solution.

Start writing unit tests before you begin.  Maybe Selenium can help you here.

Comment: hi,
 so do you think the only way is to reduce the number of actions right? I'd say that I can reduce them, but not so much...most of them are Ajax calls anyway...

Comment: I'm suggesting that several of those Action classes have a single method.  It might be possible to combine several methods into a single class and cut down on the number of classes.  If you really need all those calls, then you need them.